# Accessing Azure Server - Request timed out

Tags: php, apache, azure, dns, ip

I just started up an Azure server and have been trying to access it for a while and am having a hard time doing so.

I installed zPanel on my 12.04 Azure Ubuntu server (like cPanel: Apache, MySQL, PHP, etc) and made sure Apache was working and pointed a domain to the server IP and gave it to zPanel's installer to config.

I tried accessing the server through direct IP, through the domain and even pinging it. I keep getting `Request timed out`.

I'm using the "Resource Manager" in Azure and can't find a way to specifically allow port 80, so I'm assuming it's enabled already, but that's the only reason I can think of for not being able to access the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the specifical port on the Azure old portal or new portal, please see the pictures below.

[image]
Fig 1. Add the endpoints(ports) on Azure old portal

[image]
Fig 2. Add the endpoints(ports) on Azure new portal

Hope it helps. Best Regards.