# How to configure and connect to a running NodeJS webapp on Azure virtual machine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, angular-fullstack

I created a virtual machine on Azure cloud. Please note it is not a classic virtual machine. I created other one. Then I logged in to the machine using Putty and installed all necessary softwares like NodeJS, MongoDB etc.

Then I created a MEAN stack application using angular-fullstack. Then I did grunt build.

Finally I went to the dist folder and started the Node app as follows:

NODE_ENV=production PORT=8080 node server/app.js

The app started successfully.

Now when I try to access the web app on Chrome or Firefox browser using IP address I cannot access it. It gives error that page not found.

https://10.25.192.29
or
https://10.25.192.29:8080

http://10.25.192.29:8080

Nothing works.

Could you please help me to let me know if I have missed any major step like configurations ?

Comment: This question probably belongs in Server Fault or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the necessary ports open on the VM.  Check the VM firewall settings in the azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption that your linux on Azure VM was not enable any security policy like firewall or iptables.

You can try to add the specifical port on the Azure old portal or new portal, please see my answer for the other thread [Accessing Azure Server - Request timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237849/accessing-azure-server-request-timed-out).